# Is less right rudder pressure needed for right chandelles

Tags: aircraft-performance, pilot-technique, maneuver, rudder, chandelle

It is said on the Internet and the FAA Airplane Flying handbook that when rolling out from a right chandelle, the yawing moment is to the right, which partially cancelled some of the left turning tendency's effect. So less right rudder pressure is needed.

However, I don't understand the above. When you turn to the right, the adverse yaw is to the left, right? Then this left yawing moment contribute more to the original left turning tendency, resulting in more left yawing moment. Then, more rudder pressure is needed in such a right chandelle?

Comment: No. It is to the left. When performing a chandelle to the right, at the end, the left wing is on the outside of the turn during the rollout, and is therefore moving faster than the right wing, and to roll to the left (rolling out of the right bank), you put the right aileron down, and the left aileron up so the adverse yaw is to the right. Both effects cause a *right* roll.

Comment: It may be more correct to say less *left* rudder pressure is needed *when rolling out* (from a right hand turn).  But if one is "finishing near stall speed", staying coordinated would be most important.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is to the left. You may be confused due to thinking that adverse yaw is the result of the direction of the bank,  (or turn), not the *roll*.. in a *right* chandelle, at the end, when rolling out to level flight you are rolling to the *left*, not to the *right*.

And this will cause adverse yaw *opposite* the *direction* of the roll, regardless of the bank angle itself. This is because the aileron deflected downwards, into the airstream on the bottom of the wing, experiences significantly higher drag than the aileron that is deflected upwards.

Also, when performing a chandelle to the right, at the end, the left wing is on the outside of the turn during the rollout, and is therefore moving faster than the right wing, and. as mentioned above, to roll to the left (rolling out of the right bank), you put the right aileron down, and the left aileron up so the adverse yaw is to the right. Both effects cause a right roll.

Comment: Understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In many aircraft, the *direction and rate of roll* is far and away the dominating factor in determining the aircraft's "adverse" or "proverse" yawing tendencies.  The nose typically tends to yaw toward the *rising* wingtip (in relation to the actual direction of the flight path at any instant.)<sup>1</sup>

Typically there are also smaller factors whose effects can be noticed while turning with a constant bank angle, which tend to yaw the nose slightly toward the outside of the turn (in relation to the actual direction of the flight path at any instant.)

Which way are we rolling when exiting a right chandelle?  To the left.  It's only because the roll rate is fairly low that any right rudder (to overcome P-factor) is needed at all; with a higher roll rate you'd need to apply left rudder to keep the ball centered.

Footnotes:

1. Note that when we start to enter a turn from wings-level flight, since our flight path is initially linear, the aircraft's tendency to yaw toward the rising wingtip *in relation to the actual direction of the flight path at any instant* will also produce a visible "wrong-way" swing of the nose *in relation to a distant landmark ahead of the airplane*.  This is generally not the case when we are rolling *out* of a turn, unless the turn rate is rather low and we are using a rather strong roll input, which is an unusual combination.

Comment: (not much different than the other existing answer, just a slightly slightly different spin on things)